# How do I compile the Google Play libraries under Android Studio preview edition?

Tags: android, build, android-studio

I'm trying to write an app with the new Android Studio which will use the Google Play APIs, but I don't know how to include that library in the build process.

- My app is named MyApp.
- I already have the API keys set up in the Google API console and the appropriate changes made to my AndroidManifest.xml per the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) guide.
- I've also already downloaded the Google Play Services from within the SDK manager (Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are on MacOS, and that you have saved your project in the default location, you should have a `~/Android\ Studio\ Projects/MyAppProject` directory.

1. From a Terminal window, copy the Play Services project directory into your project: `cp -R /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib ~/Android\ Studio\ Projects/MyAppProject` .  You should now have a directory like `MyAppProject/google-play-services_lib` .
2. Save this build script as `MyAppProject/google-play-services_lib/build.gradle` and edit the compileSdkVersion if needed:

   ```
   buildscript {
        repositories {
             maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        }
        dependencies {
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
        }
   }
   apply plugin: 'android-library'

   dependencies {
        compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
   }

   android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
        sourceSets {
             main {
                   manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                   res.srcDirs = ['res']
             }
        }
   }
   ```
3. Edit your `settings.gradle` file to include the project: `include ':MyApp', ':google-play-services_lib'`
4. Edit your project's build file (`MyApp/build.gradle`) to include the Play project as a dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
       compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') //if needed
   }
   ```
5. Inform the IDE about the library so that you can have autocomplete.  Visit File -> Project Structure -> Libraries, click the + sign, select Java, and select `MyAppProject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

You should now be able to build and run the app without any errors.  Recall that the Google Play APIs are not available in the emulator, so you'll need to test on a real device.  You will also need to make sure that your keystore is configured in order to pass authentication.